# How to find uniqueness of trillions of data in java using spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I used below code to collect millions and trillions of data which is stored in my sample text file. I am collecting it into output variable. But unable to store this huge amount of data temporary, for this issue I used queue but also unable to compare values for finding uniqueness of data i.e(Each rows should be unique want to compare all the values with one another).

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("JavaWordCount").getOrCreate();

JavaRDD<String> lines = spark.read()
                .textFile("Sample.txt").javaRDD();

JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(
                SPACE.split(s)).iterator());
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = words
                .mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1));            
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = ones
                .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);
List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> output = counts.collect();
```

And also `ones.reduceByKey` this method is getting only distinct data because of this data is losses for data below 10 millions.

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are trying to do here.  The code looks like you are trying to compute occurrence counts for each word.  But what I don't understand is why you are doing it using Spark.  There is a serial bottle-neck when you read the lines of the file, and the rest of the computation is computationally cheap compared to that.

Comment: And what do you mean by "this method is getting only distinct data because of this data is losses for data below 10 millions"?  That sentence simply doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @StephenC 
1.Using spark i'm doing it because it saves my computation time as compared to buffered reader, my file size is huge.
2. If we pass a file containing 3 millions of duplicate data so this method ones.reduceByKey returns only distinct data, thus the occurrence of remaining data is lost and cant perform further operation.

Comment: Sorry.  I don't understand.  You want count the words AND do something else?  So why don't you stream the file twice?

Comment: I want to count the words for comparison with all the other word to find the uniqueness of data. We are unable to stream the file twice it increases our computational time because data is in millions.

Comment: And going back and using `words` a second time doesn't work?